# Regular expression not showing multiple line content

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I have a file with following format.

```
<hello>
<random1>
<random2>
....
....
....
<random100>
<bye>
```

I want to find whether bye and hello are there, and bye is below hello. I tried this regular expression.

`grep "hello.*bye" filename`

but it fails to match what I expected.

Comment: the "regexp" is matched against a *single line*.

Comment: are those the first and last line? how about checking `head` and `tail`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M 'hello(\n|.)*bye' filename
```

The `-M` option makes it possible to search for patterns that span line boundaries.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
<hello>
<random1>
<random2>
....
....
....
<random100>
<bye>
```

Comment: +1, but not all platforms come with `pcregrep` (not available on OSX and Debian, for instance); do you know which ones do?

Comment: @mklement0 I believe that it's available by default on Ubuntu, variants of BSD, RedHat.  It should be available for Debian too, I believe.  Can't say by OSX, don't use (prefer) it much.

Comment: @devnull It's not available on an Ubuntu Server box I just checked. EDIT: *not* available.

Comment: Have an upvote for brevity and since I didn't even know about `pcregrep` :-)

Answer (score 1):

IF the input file is small enough, you can try:

```
grep "hello.*bye"  <(tr $'\n' ' ' < filename)
```

This replaces all newlines with spaces and thus turns the file contents into a single line that grep searches at once.

If you'd rather simply *remove* newlines, use:

```
grep "hello.*bye"  <(tr -d $'\n' < filename)
```

Comment: +1 since you specifically mention that this is only a good idea for small files.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1.txt
<hello>
<bye>

$ awk '/<hello>/ {hello=1} /<bye>/&&hello {bye=1; exit} END {exit !(hello && bye)}' \
    file1.txt \
    && echo found || echo not found
found

$ cat file2.txt
<bye>
<hello>

$ awk '/<hello>/ {hello=1} /<bye>/&&hello {bye=1; exit} END {exit !(hello && bye)}' \
    file2.txt \
    && echo found || echo not found
not found
```

Comment: you can short circuit when finding 'bye'.

Comment: +1; to fully short-circuit, add `; exit ` after `bye=1`, i.e.: `awk '/<hello>/ {hello=1} /<bye>/&&hello { bye=1; exit } END { exit !(hello && bye) }'` - note that the `END` block is _still_ executed, despite the `exit` in the preceding block.

Comment: @mklement0 Heh, I guess that's what Karoly meant...of course you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perl:

```
perl -0777 -lne 'print (/hello.*bye/s ? "y" : "n")'
```

or

```
perl -0777 -ne 'exit(! /hello.*bye/s)'
```

The -0777 options slurps the whole file as a single string. The "s" flag tells perl to allow "." to match a newline.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for a multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='^$' '{print (/hello.*bye/ ? "y" : "n")}'
```